# RegEx for matching two letters with special boundaries

Tags: c, regex

I want to make sure user input has:

- Two letters at the start
- And the support for any number of optional space characters following these two letters.
- Additionally, if at least one space character is provided, optionally allow letters, digits or `.` characters after it.

Here's the expression I currently have:

`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z] (?\\s+ (?a-zA-Z0-9.))`

And here's my thinking:

`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]` makes sure the input begins with at least two letters

`(?\\s+` begins an optional statement. This optional statement must start with at least one space (I'm on windows which is why I have two slashes).

`(?a-zA-Z0-9.))` finishes the optional statement. So, if at least one space is provided, at least one optional character, number or . can also be added.

For instance, `ab`, `ab`  , `ab .s`, and `ab    .asd2` should all be valid inputs.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: \ is a backslash, not a slash.

Comment: What does your OS have to do with regexes?

Comment: `(?\\ ` is a syntax error, not an optional statement (what's a "statement" in the context of regexes?).

Comment: Is the C tag appropriate on this?

Comment: What regex library are you using?

Comment: @melpomene I see what you're saying. I've cleared up that bit of confusion. After the two characters, any number of space can be provided. Also, for windows, my command line won't recognize `\s` because it thinks its a similar character to `\n` or `\t`. So for regex, I need to use two backslashes to indicate that it isn't one of those kinds of characters. I'm also using <regex.h>

Comment: `A minimum of at least two letters` so what it can have 2 million letters then ? Where are they in the string ? You haven't described enough to write a regex yet !! There is no way to trick me, if I say it's incomplete, it is ..

Comment: `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]` matches exactly two characters, not at least two.

Comment: @poppinMartinellis Is that the POSIX `regcomp` / `regexec` stuff? I thought Windows didn't support that.

Comment: @sln, you're right, I meant the user must specify two letters. Just cleared that up in the question.

Comment: @ggorlen stack suggested I include I language tag for specificity.

Comment: @melpomene you're right, It is that. I don't know much about it, but I can tell you I am able to run regex expressions just fine

Comment: Cool, then you just need to read up on POSIX regex syntax. It doesn't support `\s` or `(?`.

Comment: @Emma I did include some sample outputs at the bottom of my question. Would more specific ones help?

Comment: By "space", do you mean the ASCII space character (code 32) or any whitespace character (including tab, newline, etc.)?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, just the specific space character.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your attempt is that both `(?\` and `(?a` are syntax errors. If you want to create an optional group, you need to write `(...)?`, not `(?...)`.

(The other issue is that `a-zA-Z0-9` in your regex matches literally because it's not part of a character class.)

Besides, `\s` (to match whitespace) does not exist in POSIX regex.

My suggestion:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}( +[a-zA-Z0-9.]*)?$
```

That is:

```
^                # beginning of string
[a-zA-Z]{2}      # exactly two letters
(
  \ +            # one or more spaces
  [a-zA-Z0-9.]*  # zero or more of: letters, digits, or dot
)?               # ... this group is optional
$                # end of string
```

Comment: @sln No, it isn't. Mine doesn't use `(?:` (which is a syntax error in POSIX) or `\d` (which doesn't exist in POSIX), and it allows multiple trailing characters (yours only allows one).

Comment: You quibble about POSIX, which I don't know, it was before my time. And I don't think it allows range quantifiers either. Nobody mentioned POSIX, its not in the title, nor question body. And, somebody changed the spec after I posted, it was a single letter, digit, or dot at the end, not multiple.

Comment: @sln Even the very first version of the spec said "*allow the option of **at least one** letter, digit or . character after it.*" Also see OP's original examples of valid inputs at the end of the question; those have been there since the first revision, too.

Comment: @sln I don't "quibble" about POSIX; it's simply what OP is using. They used a `c` tag on the question (the original title even said something about "regex in C"). In the comments OP then clarified they're using `<regex.h>`, which is a POSIX library.

Comment: You assume too much `<regex.h>` is the header for ECMAScript engine. `C` is a subset of C++, so POSIX can't really be inferred. When was the last c compiler written, about 20 years ago ?

Comment: @sln [Here's the POSIX regex specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_06) where it defines the meaning of `{m}`, `{m,}`, and `{m,n}` (which it calls "interval expressions").

Comment: @sln Which "ECMAScript engine" are you talking about? C is not a subset of C++. The latest C compiler came out just yesterday (version 9.1 of GCC). I didn't infer POSIX; I asked OP: "*Is that the POSIX regcomp / regexec stuff?*" and they replied: "*you're right, It is that.*"

Comment: That's ere, extended, which also allows `(?:)` notation as well as non-greedy quantifier syntax `+?` ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192875/discussion-between-melpomene-and-sln).

Comment: Yeah, since c is a subset of c++.. What exact c specification is new with gcc ? Since the C spec hasn't changed in 20 years, nothing is new .